# Why is it so difficult to convert XML to pdf?

Tags: xml, pdf, xml-parsing

Could anybody explain to me why is it so complicated to create a pdf file from xml sheet? Acrobat can create XML File but when I want to do this other way round it suddenly gets complicated. I would like to find some simple application which would allow me to create a pdf file out of xml. Is it possible?

Comment: How would this magical application know how the data in the XML is meant to be formatted?

Comment: Anyway, this isn't a very good question. If you're trying to accomplish something specific, ask how to do that, but nobody here can explain some vague gripe you have.

Comment: Okay, let's be more specific - I need to replace few lines in a pdf file. I haven't got the source document and I haven't got professional version of Adobe Acrobat. So I thought that if I saved this file as a XML file (which my version of Adobe Acrobat can do) replace the copy in this XML file I would be able to somehow convert it back to pdf...but this is probably not the most clever solution...I guess I'll use photoshop.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

XML is a bunch of ingredients, PDF is the finished meal.

Those who know how to cook can create a wide variety of meals using the same ingredients. With a potato, he can create soup, mashed potatoes, crisps, french fries,... There's an almost endless list of possibilities.

Those who can't cook, will stare at the potato and wonder: *How on earth can I turn this ugly vegetable into a nice croquette?*

The answer is: you need a recipe. That recipe could be an XSL:FO file, the XHTML specification, a DocBook implementation, an XFA template,... Without that recipe, you'll never be able to turn your XML into PDF.

Comment: Thanks Bruno - I guess this XSL:FO is some kind of stylesheet (similar to CSS file). So what do I need? Some specific application which creates this XSL:FO file out of my pdf?

Comment: @DDEX You mention you want to "replace some lines". Going by this analogy, what you want to do is take blended potato soup and replace the potato in it with sweet potato. PDF is a display format - internally it's mainly pictures of letters absolutely positioned on pages - it's not designed to be "editable" in any meaningful way like a Word document would be, and I doubt the XML you get from Acrobat is meant for this sort of round-trip change. It is possible to "reflow" an existing PDF document to make this sort of edits but it's impractically difficult.

Comment: @Bruno: I see - thank you. Your potato example was worth the minus points in my reputation score.

Comment: XSL:FO is only one option. Personally, I prefer XFA. It allows you to create a template using Adobe LiveCycle Designer (shipped with Acrobat) and you can inject your own XML into the template to render it. But that's a personal preference. I really hate writing XSL:FO; others love it.

Comment: I didn't vote your question down. I see that 2 people voted to close the question... I didn't, but I agree: this isn't really a question for StackOverflow.